# How do you detect order execution algorithms?

Tags: market-microstructure, market-making, algorithmic-trading

Most large orders nowadays are done through TWAP or VWAP based order execution. For example, if Alice wants to sell $60 million in EURUSD she will break up her order into 50,000 tiny orders and then send them to the broker over the course of T time.

Are there any papers/known methods in detecting such behaviour?

Comment: after detecting a trader's strategy, what use does knowing it have, or what do you plan to do with that information

Comment: The first generation of algos broke things up in exactly equal sized orders so people looked for recurrent sized orders (e.g. 1357 shares). I assume the game is more sophisticated nowadays and more difficult to detect.

Comment: What you describe in the example is Accumulate Distribute https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=4985, not VWAP or TWAP. Size is random, interval is random.

Comment: @SergeiRodionov That link is really useful thanks.